# Binding the click event to jquery mobile buttons is not working when clicking the border

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

this is my first question and I hope I've done enough research to be sure it has not been aksed before. Im wondering nobody else has this problem.

I've created a fiddle to illustrate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/KA54D/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>Page 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <button data-icon="check">Click me at my border</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Using the following JavaScript Code:

```
$('button').click(
  function() {
    $('.ui-content').append('click ');
  }
);
```

When binding a click-event to a button, this event is not fired, when clicking on the border of a button. But the down-state of the style is triggered.

I don't like constructs like:

```
$('button').closest('.ui-btn').click(...)
```

because it's not really fluid. At designtime there is no .ui-btn, because it's added later by the framework. I don't want to care about, whats internally done by the lib. Is there a way to tell jQuery Mobile to reassign the events, attributes, css-classes etc. to the containing element of my button?

Comment: Anytime my cursor becomes a hand, the click event fires. Sorry, but I'm not seeing an issue.

Comment: @DevlshOne Then you're not doing it right. Click on the outermost pixel border and the `click` text won't be appended

Comment: @Ian Are you talking about the button's drop shadow? This thing works great for me.

Comment: The border is 1 pixel wide. In this border the blue glow effect is missing and the click is not triggered. You can see the hand cursor and the down-effect (without glow). Using firefox currently.

Comment: @DevlshOne No, the immediate border. The first pixel where the cursor becomes a hand pointer

Comment: converting it to `a` eliminates the problem, and it doesn't wrap the button with a div http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/KA54D/10/

Comment: @Omar omg, really. Thanks a lot, this will help. Please provide it as an answer, if you'd like to get it the accepted one.

Comment: @SuperNova  see the demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Jfguq/5/

Comment: @Tushar Gupta: I've accepted Omar's solution now. Your solution still does not work. However, this is to much sourcecode to bind a button click at the border.

Comment: @SuperNova yes Omar solution is very good . :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `<button>` or `<input type="submit">`, use `<a>` with `data-role="button"` attribute.

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="check">Button</a>
```

Anchors with `data-role=button` dont get wrapped with a `.ui-btn` div. Hence, you have will have the whole button responsive to any event.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the event is not fired on about 1-2 px of the border, I think this is due to the way jQuery Mobile manages your button and creates a final component, may be they create a special border around your initial button which is not part of the button.

All in all, I don't think this is a problem because no user will click around 1 to 2 px on the border.

Comment: Our users which are using the interface with mouse reported this problem many times, because some buttons are not working with the first click. When using touch ONLY devices this doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the actual components that make up the button, maybe this explains the issue..
It would be interesting to see if the event triggers off of the `button` element, the surrounding `div` or something else!

```
<div data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="check" data-theme="c" data-disabled="false" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-c" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Click me at my border</span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
    </span>
    <button data-icon="check" class="ui-btn-hidden" data-disabled="false">Click me at my border</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The event.target is the <button>-Element.

Comment: Bummer... probably not much you can do about it, then. Except, treat it as you would a `disabled` button and create a fake span around it, with an `id` that could be included in the `.click()` selectors.

Comment: I tried this, but it has other drawbacks: buttons can be styled by the ui (noicon, floating, inside a grid) and my outer div is not getting themed than. I think I have to open a bug tracker entry, if I cannot find a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I've found another CSS-only solution now:

```
.ui-btn button {
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 0 2px 2px 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.ui-header .ui-btn button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1px 0;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

However, I'll keep my accepted answer, because this answer does not need any modifications to jQueryMobile itself.